# react navigation headerTitle option is unable to render a View

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to render a view as a custom header with react navigation v5

My code:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
 screenOptions={{
   headerTitle: <View> <Text> a </Text><Text> b </Text> </View>
}}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={tabNavigator}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

I also tried

```js
const Header = () => <View> <Text> a </Text> <Text> b </Text> </View>

<Stack.Navigator
 screenOptions={{
  headerTitle: <Header />
  }}
>
   <Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={tabNavigator}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

I get the following error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component

The react navigation doc shows an example of a custom header with an image instead [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/)

I think that what I´m trying to do is possible though

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component
maybe you need pass it like this
`options={{ headerTitle: props => <Header {...props} /> }}`

Comment: nope I tried that in both Stack.Navigator and Stack.Screen with no avail

Comment: are you getting the same error with the second code snippet you provided?

Comment: Yes, returning only one text component instead of a view seens to work but i don't now why

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare new component for header title.

```
class HeaderTitle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return {
      <View> <Text> a </Text><Text> b </Text> </View>
    }
  }
}
```

And you need to use header instead of headerTitle to be able to use View.

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerTitle: <HeaderTitle />
}}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={tabNavigator}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Or you can use this code.

```
static navigationOptions = {
  // headerTitle instead of title
  headerTitle: <HeaderTitle />,
};

/* render function, etc */
```

Comment: I copy and paste it and now says: header is not a function. (In 'header(props)', is an instance of Object)